# How to disable server side rendering on an asp.netcore-spa application?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I am building my application using aspnetcore-spa react-redux boilerplate (can be seen on http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/ )

However the server side rendering takes a lot of time (~30 sec) and I would like to disable it. Can you please tell me how to disable server side rendering without breaking the code?

Comment: You sure server-sided rendering is active? Hit F12 in Firefox and got to the network tab and see the files downlaoded. Sounds more like server-sided rendering is not enabled and your angular app downloads every single file (instead of bundles), which results in 400-800 requests sent to the server, which takes around 30-60 seconds. Also fetching of files from ASP.NET Core is quite slow, when debugger is enabled so it takes even longer. Maybe post your `System.config.js` file here

Comment: thanks @Tseng, I ran my application on Release mode realized only the first request takes long since webpack generates the bundle in ~16 seconds. After that it runs fast.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That template adds the `asp-prerender-module` tag helper to the `<div id="react-app"...>` tag in `Home\Index.cshtml`.  If you remove that tag helper you will disable server side rendering.

The tag helper is imported in `/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`:

> `@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices"`

You can do the bundling from the command line before you run the application with...

```
> webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
> webpack
```

Steve Sanderson gave a [presentation](https://vimeo.com/180155167) on this at NDC Sydney.

The [`aspnet-prerender-module`](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/Prerendering/PrerenderTagHelper.cs) tag helper is part of [`SpaServices`](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices), which is the basis for all the projects generated by the Yeoman [`aspnetcore-spa`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnetcore-spa) templates.  Therefore, this is how you would enable/disable pre-rendering in any of those templates, including `Angular 2`, `Aurelia`, `Knockout`, and `React (with Redux)`.  The same would apply to any custom project or template that you create using `Node` package [`aspnet-prerendering`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aspnet-prerendering) and the aforementioned tag helper.

Comment: I have followed Steve Sanderson's blog and have added primeng for data tables, datatable module works only if I remove the "aspnet-prerender-module" attribute from <app></app> element in my index.cshtml file. Is it possible to keep both? I want to keep this pre-render-module and any third party node_module. Same happened when I tried to install kendo data tablea node module. is there any compatibility issue or I'm doing something wrong? do we have  any solution to this?

Comment: @sohaibjaved Your situation probably deserves its own question.  I have some workarounds, but I don't think they would apply to that particular libarary.  Some libraries are just not compatible with isomorphic rendering right now.  I have run in to several different scenarios where server prerender seemed unlikely, but have managed to find workarounds that involve one or a combination of the following:

Comment: @sohaibjaved 1. `import { isBrowser } from 'angular2-universal'` (which should probably be coming from core by now) and conditionally allow/postpone certain functionality until you know you're in the client context.  2. if you need to load an npm package for side effects (doesn't apply to your situation) you can do so in `boot-client.ts`. 3. Declare an object to hold the symbol you want to use.  Then, instead of using `import`, conditionally use `require` to override something you've previously declared.  Unfortunately I don't think any of these will work in your particular situation.

Comment: Great thanks for your help Let me give it a try if it doesn't work then I'll surely create a question for this situation, as I'm finding pre-rendering incompatible with any 3rd party node module.

Comment: This might be a good place to start research on workarounds for using certain libraries with universal: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/308#issuecomment-247757585  Well, maybe not a good place to start, but I think that thread gets to the heart of the matter.  I don't know how to deal with the custom tags themselves.  I would try to hide that section of the page until you're sure all required assets have loaded on the client.  So that's what I was referring to with conditionally setting some flag based on `isBrowser`, and using `*ngIf`

Comment: perfect, you put really well, I'm starting with this url, I'm sure its some kinda dependency (with some particular version of node module) issue. However  I tried this isBrowser once didn't work for me need to give it another try maybe in a separate application to better figureout.

Comment: This does not work for me. I only get a blank page after doing this.

Answer (score 7):

For Angular 2 project I've solved this by removing `asp-prerender-module` attribute from `<app>` tag in Index.schtml.